# Construct a restriction map of a linear fragment of DNA using the following data?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, homework

I've attempted to do the single digests, and the double digests, but cannot complete the map.... I've attached what I've done so far

[image]

DNA Sizes of Fragments (bp)

uncut DNA 900

DNA cut with EcoRI 500, 350, 50

DNA cut with HindIII 600, 300

DNA cut with BamHI 400, 300, 200

DNA cut with EcoRI + HindIII 350, 300, 200, 50

DNA cut with EcoRI + BamHI 300, 250, 200, 100, 50

DNA cut with HindIII + BamHI 300, 200, 100

Comment: Why are you listing only one of the possible fragment orderings for each cut result?  (e.g. only 500, 350, 50 and not the other five arrangements, like 350, 50, 500 and 50, 350, 500)

Comment: ^This. You need to list all arrangements possible. It is equally possible for the enzymes to cut in any order (theoretically). Unless specified in which order they are used.